# How to display 'console.log' output in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console.log

How do I see this message in Visual Studio Code as JS?

```
let count = 0

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After saving the changes in the file press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> than it will ask you to select environment, then select node and it will give you the answer in your Debug Console.

To open the Debug Console press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Comment: It doesn't show `node` option